# Extract text enclosed between a delimiter and store it as a list in a separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Panda` dataframe with a text column in the format below. There are some values/text meshed in between `##`. I want to find such text which are present between `##` and extract them in a separate column as a list.

```
##fare_curr.currency####based_fare_90d.price##

htt://www.abcd.lol/abcd-Search?from:##based_best_flight_fare_90d.air##,to:##mbased_90d.water##,departure:##mbased_90d.date_1##TANYT&pas=ch:0Y&mode=search
```

Consider the above two strings to be two rows of the same column. I want to get a new column with a `list [fare_curr.currency, based_fare_90d.price]` in the first row and `[based_best_flight_fare_90d.air, mbased_90d.water, based_90d.date_1]` in the second row.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the string and what is the exact output expected?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific about what i want in the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':
['##fare_curr.currency####based_fare_90d.price##',
'htt://www.abcd.lol/abcd-Search?\ from:##based_best_flight_fare_90d.air##,to:##mbased_90d.water##,departure:#
#mbased_90d.date_1##TANYT&pas=ch:0Y&mode=search']})
```

You can get desired result in a new column using

```
df['new'] = pd.Series(df.data.str.extractall('##(.*?)##').unstack().values.tolist())
```

You get

```
    data                                            new
0   ##fare_curr.currency####based_fare_90d.price##  [fare_curr.currency, based_fare_90d.price, None]
1   htt://www.abcd.lol/abcd-Search?from:##based_be...   [based_best_flight_fare_90d.air, mbased_90d.wa...
```